# Keycloak integration with Atlassian Crowd

Tags: keycloak, atlassian-crowd

We have a software stack with authentication based on keycloak.
A client asks us to handle users / roles in its own system (Atlassian Crowd).

Is there a way to connect both, so we don't have to redevelop the authentication layer in our apps ?

- Import Crowd users/roles into keycloak regularly ?
- Delegate keycloak users authentication to Crowd (how ?)
- ... ?

I have no deep knowledge about auth mechanisms (Usage of keycloak in our software stack is pretty simple), but would like to have a picture about what's possible.

Comment: You can create a custom authenticator to make a REST API call to Crowd.  Both your Keycloak and Crowd can sync with an LDAP server to get account information.  In this manner you can use Keycloak to authenticate a user and then use the custom authenticator to get a Crowd session cookie (based on roles, groups, etc.).  Both the Keycloak token and Crowd session cookie can be delivered to the client who will use them to access the webserver/application.